# How can I outptut Findstr into an IF exist statement?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to work on a game using Batch file work, and I'm still a little new to the work. The game is going to be similar to a hacking simulator (it isn't really hacking, just makes it look like it), but will be a multiplayer game, where one team is R and the other is B.

In the game, the user is required to find the mixed usernames and passwords and match them to hack a user on the game. For instance, if the user wants to hack User1, he/she needs to find the password of User1 through all the randomly generated password files.

In order for them to do so, they need to know the username and password. The username part I got, where the batch file sees if the user exists, but now it needs to determine the password match. Here's the code:

```
:authousrrgy
echo AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED! PLEASE ENTER THE USER'S PASSWORD!
set /p usrpwd=^>
if "%userpwd%"=="%userpwd%" goto authredusr
:authredusr
echo Authenticating, please wait
if exist R\Orig-UserAuth\"%userpwd%" goto checkpwd
if not exist R\Orig-UserAuth\"%userpwd%" goto Authfail1
:Authfail1
echo Authentication Failed. User doesn't exist.
goto gwayred
:checkpwd
```

On checkpwd is where I need the help on. There will be the mixed username and passwords folder called userauth (where users can only read the files using ls), and there is the original user authentication folder, where the name of each file will be the user and the passwords will be contained in the folders. I need the one the user inputs onto the command line to match the one provided in the original userauth.

Comment: What is your question? I read your long (and somewhat confusing) description and can't found any question...

Comment: Basically I want the If Exist statement to be able to see if text is found in a document other than having to use it to find files, then be able to take an action. For instance, I want it to do: If exist "string found in the file.exension" goto attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F "delims=" %%e in ('type ip.txt ^| findstr Server:') do set storevariable=%%e
```

Replace ip.txt to the actual file name and Server: to the findstr variable and the output will be stored in the variable name storevariable.

```
echo %storevariable% will show the output value.
```